# Can I create an SQL database from Subsonic (reverse)?

Tags: subsonic

I had just lost my database and all the backups, I know it is pathetic at the first place but again .. bad things do happen :). Now I have a complete source code generated by SubSonic against my database. I was wondering is there a way I can recreate my database using Subsonic ??

Answer (score 0):

No, SubSonic does not have a way to recreate the database from the generated SubSonic source.  What you are asking is possible to do, but you'll have find another solution or write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of [SubSonic Simple repository](http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository) functions, it will not recreate your releationships, but should be able to effectivevly create your database based on your class files.

It might be some work though, cause you will have to mark your classess with a couple of attributes

Read more here: http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository